# How can we remove/delete the custom attribute(created for customer) in Magento 2

Tags: customer-attribute, magento-2.0.4, magento-2.1.4

I want to remove the custom attribute created for customer using installchema,I followed this [link](http://Magento%202%20How%20to%20uninstall%20attributes%20added%20by%20custom%20module?) but it didn't helped.Anyone tried earlier,please help.Thanks in advance!
I have added attribute manually using installschema script and the code is here

```
namespace Bibhu\Customattribute\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Sample Attribute',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'required' => true,
                'default' => '0',
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'system' => false,
                'position' => 100
            ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'sample_attribute');
        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        );
        $sampleAttribute->save();

            }
}
```

and to remove using this Uninstall.php script

```
    <?php
namespace Bibhu\Customattribute\Setup ;

    class Uninstall implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface
    {
        protected $eavSetupFactory;
        public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }
        public function uninstall(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
            $entityTypeId = 1; 
            $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'sample_attribute');
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

You should use UpgradeData now.

Create this file **app/code/Bibhu/Customattribute/Setup/UpgradeData.php** :

```
namespace Bibhu\Customattribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

/**
 * Class UpgradeData
 * @package Bibhu\Customattribute\Setup
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0) {
            $this->upgradeSchema201($setup);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     */
    private function upgradeSchema201(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute'
        );
    }
}
```

... change your module version (make sure to increase it) in **app/code/Bibhu/Customattribute/etc/module.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Bibhu_Customattribute" setup_version="2.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

... then **update your module** using command line :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

I use customer setup to delete custom customer attribute in my controller, after delete the custom customer attribute i clean the cache programmatically, the whole code goes like this:

```
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory; 

class Delete  extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, ,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory =$customerSetupFactory; 
        $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
        $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
     $this->attribute_code = 'custom_attribute_code';
     $this->removeEavCustomer();
    }

    private function removeEavCustomer(){
      $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create();
      $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $this->attribute_code);

      $this->cleanCache();
    }

    private function cleanCache(){
      $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
      foreach ($types as $type) {
          $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
      }
      foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
          $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below script

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
 $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom-attribute-code');
```

Comment: i tried this but not working

Answer (score 0):

Okay,it may be not the right way but I am able to delete the attribute by removing the particular attribute row from eav_attribute table from my db.